# How to work with multiple databases in Django [using Database Routers]

Tags: python, django

I need to isolate django`s default (auth, contenttypes, sessions) apps database, I read in documentation [Multiple Databses][1] all is clear and well explained, but not working to me :(

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default_django': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
},
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c search_path=eos,public'
    },
    'NAME': '****',
    'USER': '*****',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}

}

DATABASE_ROUTES = ['core.dbrouter.AuthRoute', 'core.dbrouter.GisRoute']
```

and ./core/dbrouter.py

```
class AuthRouter:
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
"""
route_app_labels = {
    'auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes',
    'sessions', 'messages', 'staticfiles'
}

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return 'default_django'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return 'default_django'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
    involved.
    """
    if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
    ):
        return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
    'auth_db' database.
    """
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return db == 'default_django'
    return None
```

When I do `python3 manage.py migrate` it is shows

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Please, could someone explain?(Why?)
[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Did you try specifying the DB? `python3 manage.py migrate --database=default_django` ?  From the docs "By default, it operates on the default database"

Comment: Yes, it works, but why I need to use Routers, then?

Comment: I thought routers automatically handle this?

Comment: The router automatically handles it for the rest of the dB access.  Request read/writes etc.

Comment: Okay, clean! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot an R.

```py
DATABASE_ROUTES = ['core.dbrouter.AuthRoute', 'core.dbrouter.GisRoute']
              ↓
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['core.dbrouter.AuthRoute', 'core.dbrouter.GisRoute']
```